# Trying to use VBA-excel to filter one worksheet based on clicked value in another workseet

Tags: filter, excel, vba

OK, I'm a total VBA noob, so excuse my awful code.

I have two excel worksheets, one titled 'Contractors' and one titled 'Referring_to_Contractors'.

The contractors sheet is laid out like so.

Terr   ContractorID   First  Last
1            7         Bob    Smith
2            5         Jeff    Brown
3            8         Stan    Lee

The Referring_to_Contractors sheet has the same fields and layout as the Contractors sheet above, but also has additional columns for Referring Contractors,  so it has columns titled "Ref_Contractor_Id", "Ref_First",  "Ref_Last", etc.

What I'm trying to do is use VBA so that when someone double clicks a row in the "Contractors" sheet,  it will take the value in the Contractor_ID column, then look in the "Referring_to_Contractors"  sheet and filter by all records in that sheet that have that value as Contractor_ID.  Essentially, this would display referral information for the Contractor_ID clicked on the first sheet.  I created a named range for the Contractor_ID field titled "PrimaryContractor"

So, on the first sheet 'Contractors', I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

and..

```
Sub Select_Ref_Contractors()

    ContractorId = Range("PrimaryContractor").Value

    With Sheets("Referring_to_Contractors")
        .Visible = True
        .Select
   End With

    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$10:$N$44163).AutoFilter Field: =1, Criteria1:= ContractorID

    Application.Goto Range("A1"), True

End Sub
```

Conceptually this seems like it should be pretty simple yet for some reason I can't get the second sheet to filter correctly.

Any helps or even useful links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just knocked this up in Excel 2007 and it seems to work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim id As String

If Not Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    id = CStr(Selection)

    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheet2.Range("A1", "c4").AutoFilter 1, id
End If
End Sub
```

It is using the same table on both sheets as below and when you double click a cell on Sheet1, the BeforeDoubleClick event fires and puts you onto Sheet2 with the filter applied.

```
ID  ID2 Text
1   2   a
2   2   b
3   3   c
```

Comment: It does have flaws (aka errors) if you select multiple cells, but a bit of checking should fix that